# How do I change the "+" to a "-" sign when the accordion is open?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

As stated in the question, how do I get the "+" sign to correctly change to a "-" sign when the answer, of the question that's clicked, is visible.

At the moment, the "+" sign changes to a "-" sign when the question is clicked twice.

To summarize, I just want the "+" sign to be visible when a question's answer is closed, and the "-" sign to be visible when a question's answer is open.

```js
// Change +/-
$(".question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  } else if ($(".question").next().is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
});

// FAQ
$(".question").click(function() {
  $(".answer").slideUp();
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
  } else {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.question {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.question:before {
  content: "+";
  color: #008aff;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.question.active:before {
  content: '-';
  margin-right: 13.86px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Question 1</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
  <div class="question">Question 2</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
  <div class="question">Question 3</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your active class is not added correctly

Comment: I would also combined $(".question").click into one event instead of two

Comment: You're observing the click event twice. No need. http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/xt679fnw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the addClass and removeClass the wrong way around. You should also apply the removeClass to all the other questions to ensure the + is displayed when not displayed.

```js
// Change +/-
$(".question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  } else if ($(".question").next().is(":hidden")) {
    $('.question').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});

// FAQ
$(".question").click(function() {
  $(".answer").slideUp();
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
  } else {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.question {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.question:before {
  content: "+";
  color: #008aff;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.question.active:before {
  content: '-';
  margin-right: 13.86px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Question 1</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
  <div class="question">Question 2</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
  <div class="question">Question 3</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for not only the answer, but for considering the removal of the "+" sign when another question is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the `addClass` and `removeClass` calls.

So this block:

```
// Change +/-
$(".question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  } else if ($(".question").next().is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

should be:

```
// Change +/-
$(".question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active"); // switched
  } else if ($(".question").next().is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).addClass("active"); // switched
  }
});
```

Result:

```js
// Change +/-
$(".question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  } else if ($(".question").next().is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});

// FAQ
$(".question").click(function() {
  $(".answer").slideUp();
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
  } else {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.question {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.question:before {
  content: "+";
  color: #008aff;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.question.active:before {
  content: '-';
  margin-right: 13.86px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Question 1</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
  <div class="question">Question 2</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
  <div class="question">Question 3</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By splitting the show/hide and +/- behavior into two separate functions, you introduce the added complexity of relying on jquery to run one before there other, and I don't know how jquery decides which to run first.

I suggest you do both things in the same function so you make sure the state is maintained correctly.

```js
// Change +/-
$(".question").click(function() {
  $(".answer").slideUp();
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().slideUp();
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next().slideDown();
  }

});
```

```css
.question {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.question:before {
  content: "+";
  color: #008aff;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.question.active:before {
  content: '-';
  margin-right: 13.86px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">Question 1</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
  <div class="question">Question 2</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
  <div class="question">Question 3</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
</div>
```